# Path issue while doing ajax request to wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have found an issue with my jquery code,
I have written a code for ajax request to wordpress,

```
jQuery.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',data,function(resp){});
```

when i use this code with url something like **"example.com"** it runs fine but when i install my code on domain something like **"example.com/blog"** it failed to run and return "**-1**", so in my opinion it is happening because it not getting **"/blog"**.

Comment: replace `'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'` with `ajaxurl` as `ajaxurl` is a global variable based on the path to the file location, since WP 3.0

Comment: thanks, is ajaxurl php global varibale? beacsue i wrote my code in js file so don't know how to access this, or i have ot just replace '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' string 'ajaxurl' string in jQuery.post?

Comment: it is a global variable wordpress provides.

Comment: thnks for replying.
i have replaced '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' with ajaxurl in my jquery post code but didn't work. and even i have tried to echo it in php like that - global $ajaxurl; echo "url:".$ajaxurl; but it prints "url" string only, please suggest what should i do

Comment: i have found out why ajaxurl is not working it is because script should be in admin_footer, thanks Ohgodwhy :)